# Constraints for iPhone 5, UIView contents overflowing

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I keep having problems with constraints on this layout (viewed as iPhone 7):
http://imgur.com/a/NJpaY

How its layered: http://imgur.com/a/W2NaS

The result on an iPhone 5S is:
http://imgur.com/a/8o4VB

I want the 0s, and the lost, poor, average, good labels in the green bit, in line, like is shown in the first screenshot from xcode.

The green bit is a UIView, which has another UIView behind it.

Any ideas what constraints to set so I can make it all line up correctly?

Comment: just pin lost to the left green view and pin good to the right green view? also checked font resizing for label

Comment: @Tj3n I did that and I get this http://imgur.com/a/0uyl9 :(

Comment: Are those text label view all subviews of the green view?  Of just laying on top of it with the same parent view?  Looks like there is not enough room for all of them to fit, in any case, and you may need to consider making them smaller (as a side issue).

Comment: This is not really a hard pin, you just make sure each of them pinned to 4 sides, then it will work, since your green view already have fixed height and width, it wont be problem for view that depends on it

Comment: @SonofaBeach see http://imgur.com/a/W2NaS

Comment: @Tj3n I have tried pining to all four sides. I think the text and labels are remaining at a size that is too big. :/

Comment: Give them auto shrink value, and make their width the same with `equal width`

Comment: So I've set the `Autoshrink` value to `Minimum Font Size` of 5 for the text labels, and 9 for the numeric labels. Sorry where do I set `equal width`?

Comment: @Tj3n I found how to set `equal width`, but its always greyed out when i select a label..

Comment: just select 4 of them at once then set equal width

Comment: @Tj3n ah. I selected them all at once. Its nearly there, see: http://imgur.com/a/WFctz

Comment: Constraints now look like this by the way: http://imgur.com/a/3Ld3i and http://imgur.com/a/uXpXF

Comment: Now change the auto shrink from Fixed font size to either one of the others option and you are good to go

Comment: Got it, http://imgur.com/a/5tAPf thanks! I had already set Fixed font size to minimum font scale. I guess I Command+Z'd too much at one point!